# How to manipulate DOM in Dynamics CRM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, xrm, dynamics-crm-365

Trying to manipulate the DOM by updating a field value using jQuery's append method.

Found that [DOM manipulation is not allowed in Dynamics CRM using normal javascript or jQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx#Anchor_4)

Hence tried to add an HTML Web resource with scripts in it's source tab:

The function is added in the project form and configured to be called at the `OnLoad` event. However, it gets called before the form loads.

The function works well when executed in the `console`, but when called by system, it doesn't works.

```
  setTimeout(ShowProjectAge, 3000);

  function ShowProjectAge() {

    var createdOn = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon");
    var createdOnDt = new Date(createdOn.$2_2.$2T_2);
    var today = new Date();
    var DiffDays = GetDiffDays(createdOnDt, today);

    //var projectAge = $('#processDuration').html();
    //$('#HeaderTilesWrapperLayoutElement').html(projectAge);
    //$('#HeaderTilesWrapperLayoutElement').css('color','black');

    console.log('The Project Age is ' + DiffDays);
    var div = $('#HeaderTilesWrapperLayoutElement');
    div.text('The Project Age is ' + DiffDays + ' days');
    div.css('color', 'black');
    div.css('font-weight', 'bold');
  }

  function GetDiffDays(date1, date2) {
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    return Math.round(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  }
```

**On completely loaded DOM, `ShowProjectAge` works well**. However, when called from the system, it doesn't gets loaded.

Tried using `document.ready` already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding on Dynamics CRM DOM, all javascripts are in a separate empty iframe.

The form elements are inside another empty iframe.

Notice that both of them are in the same window, hence change the line from this:

```
var div = $('#HeaderTilesWrapperLayoutElement');
```

to this:

```
var div = $('#HeaderTilesWrapperLayoutElement', window.parent.document);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, never do any DOM manipulation in CRM.  It's not worth the effort.  Ever.

Second, this can be done out of the box with zero code:

1. Create a custom Calculated Field
2. Use this formula: DiffInDays(createdon, Now())
3. Put that field on the form anywhere you want

Third, This is completely wrong:

```
var createdOn = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon");
var createdOnDt = new Date(createdOn.$2_2.$2T_2);
```

You can get the date like this:

```
var createdOnDt = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon").getValue();
```

Comment: I accept that my approach is wrong. Since, @aniljain's post more closely answers my question I'm accepting that as an answer. Many +1s for correcting me :)

Comment: Following best practices in CRM is very important.  You can't treat it like a custom web app and expect everything to keep working properly.
Anytime you feel the need to perform DOM manipulation in CRM, just stop, because you're probably taking a completely wrong approach.  If you can't find the correct way, post a more general question

Answer (score -1):

you have two option, first you can turn on "legacy form rendering" [turn on legacy rendering](http://www.powerobjects.com/2015/09/08/new-form-rendering-engine-in-dynamics-crm-2015/) or you must refactoring your code and used to supported method [link to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx)

but I'm thinking, You can not change in css using to Xrm.Page